# Make Modules_Install Fails

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, gentoo

I am trying to install kernel modules, but when I run *make modules_install,* the following appears:

```
  INSTALL virt/lib/irqbypass.ko
  DEPMOD  4.19.97-gentoo
  depmod: ERROR: openat(1023, 4.19.97-gentoo-x86_64, O_RDONLY): Too many open files
  depmod: ERROR: openat(1023, kernel, O_RDONLY): Too many open files
  depmod: ERROR: openat(1023, arch, O_RDONLY): Too many open files
  depmod: ERROR: openat(1023, crypto, O_RDONLY): Too many open files
  depmod: ERROR: openat(1023, drivers, O_RDONLY): Too many open files
  depmod: ERROR: openat(1023, fs, O_RDONLY): Too many open files
  depmod: ERROR: openat(1023, lib, O_RDONLY): Too many open files
  depmod: ERROR: openat(1023, net, O_RDONLY): Too many open files
  depmod: ERROR: openat(1023, virt, O_RDONLY): Too many open files
  depmod: ERROR: openat(1023, x86, O_RDONLY): Too many open files
  depmod: ERROR: could not create module /lib/modules/4.19.97-gentoo/4.19.97-gentoo-x86_64/4.19.97-gentoo-x86_64/4.19.97-gentoo-x86_64/4.19.97-gentoo-x86_64/4.19.97-gentoo-x86_64/4.19.97-gento
```

The last line goes on for a very long time, eventually ending with "4.19.97-gentoo-x86_64/kernel/crypto/arc4.ko: File name too long." I configured the kernel using *make menuconfig.* Aside from this, the system is working ok. I am using btrfs RAID 10. Here is the sequence of commands leading up to this point:

1. *make -j8*
2. *make modules*
3. *make modules_install*

Comment: This does not seem like a make problem. It's more likely system wide. Troubleshooting with [this answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/181408/1045725) (it's not Ubuntu specific), could help.

Comment: @runcz: It turned out that there was a symlink (/lib/modules/4.19.97-gentoo/) pointing to itself. Removing that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been resolved by removing an incorrect symlink for `/lib/modules/4.19.97-gentoo` that pointed to the same folder.  This is indicated in the last line of the error, as the output shows a seemingly endless depth of the nested directories.

> depmod: ERROR: could not create module
>   /lib/modules/4.19.97-gentoo/**4.19.97-gentoo-x86_64/4.19.97-gentoo-x86_64/4.19.97-gentoo-x86_64/4.19.97-gentoo-x86_64/4.19.97-gentoo-x86_64/4.19.97-gentoo**

The directory, without that erroneous symlink should be `/lib/modules/4.19.97-gentoo`.